# Calculating products of given length of two matrices

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have the following problem to solve. Let us have two given square matrices $A$ and $B$ of the same size and a positive integer $n$. I would like to produce all products of length at most $n$ of matrices $A$ and $B$ in all orders. I came up with the following code:

```
allProducts[a_, b_, n_] := 
 Module[{set = {a, b}, set1, set2, i = 1}, 
  While[i <= n - 1, set1 = Thread[Dot[set, a]] ;
   set2 = Thread[Dot[set, b]] ; set = Union[set, set1, set2]; i++]; 
  set]
```

This code works prefectly symbolically for any $n$ i can think of. However when I have concrete matrices $A$ and $B$ lets say of size $2\times 2$, allProducts[a,b,4] gives errors

> `Dot::rect: Nonrectangular tensor encountered.`
>
> `hread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length in  (My matrices appear here)`

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `Dot @@@ Tuples[{a, b}, 5]` should do it.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `Dot[a,b]` (`a` and `b` being atomic, e.g. symbols with no values) evaluates differently than `Dot[{a,b},{x,y}]` (i.e. the arguments being lists).

`Dot[{a, b}, x]` does not evaluate, so you can transform it using `Thread`.  `Dot[{a, b}, {x, y}]` does evaluate before it even sees `Thread`.  `Dot[{a, b}, {x, y, z}]` tries to evaluate and gives up with an error.

This explains the problems you see.

---

A simpler possible implementation is

```
kProducts[a_, b_, k_] := Dot @@@ Tuples[{a, b}, k]
allProducts[a_, b_, n_] := Catenate@Table[kProducts[a,b,k], {k, n}]
```

Comment: Thank you. This works now. When I calculated symbolically, it worked and beacuse of this I could not find the error. I am quite new @Mathematica.

Comment: What about if I want to multiply every matrix in my list by a given matrix $C$?

Comment: @Marko `c.#& /@ list`.  Look up `Map` and `Function`.

Comment: Thanks again. It seems easy when you look at worked examples from a book but when you try to work it on your own things get hard.

Comment: @Marko Yes, it takes a while to get used to thinking in terms of these constructs.  As I remember I enjoyed working through [this](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/1847/) a long time ago (though my memory might be failing me and maybe it's not as detailed after all).